# Histogram of binned data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, histogram, bin

My (huge) dataframe coming from a python code is composed of counts in different size classes for each sample as in :

```
dummy <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 12))
colnames(dummy) <- c("ID", paste("cl", c(1:11), sep = "."))
dummy$ID <- c(letters[1:10])
dummy[, -1] <- rep(round(abs(rnorm(11))*1000,0), 10)
```

I try to create histograms of the counts for each sample (ID) having size classes on X axis and counts (frequencies) on Y axis. No success with `hist()`, combining `as.numeric()` and `t()` and `as.table()` ...

I don't succeed in telling R that this data frame is (at least partly) a table with counts already distributed in bins that are the `colnames`. I'm sure I'm not the first guy looking for that but can't find the answer since two days, maybe because I don't get the right keywords (?).

Can somebody help?

Comment: Took me two seconds: try [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9133057/324364) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3789260/324364).

Answer (score 3):

A histogram is basically a special kind of barplot. So you could just use function `barplot`.

I prefer package ggplot2 for this:

```
#reshape to long format
library(reshape2)    
dummy <- melt(dummy, id.var="ID")

library(ggplot2)    
p <- ggplot(dummy, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="identity") + 
   #specifying stat_identity tells ggplot2 that the data is already binned
  facet_wrap(~ID, ncol=2)

print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. Would you figure a solution without ggplot2? I'm not used to it at all, but in a way this maybe a chance to give it a look ;-)

Answer (score 2):

ggplot2 is nice for questions like this, but you can do something with base R graphics as well.  It's not super pretty, but for example I would do :

```
par(mfrow=c(5,2))
par(mar=c(2,2,2,1))
for (i in 1:nrow(dummy)) {
  barplot(as.numeric(dummy[i,-1]), names.arg=colnames(dummy[1,-1], main=dummy[i,1])
}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 -- Indeed. And lattice would be another option, possibly after adding a grouping variable.