# Generating a histogram and density plot from binned data

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, density-plot

I've binned some data and currently have a dataframe that consists of two columns, one that specifies a bin range and another that specifies the frequency like this:-

```
> head(data)
      binRange Frequency
1    (0,0.025]        88
2 (0.025,0.05]        72
3 (0.05,0.075]        92
4  (0.075,0.1]        38
5  (0.1,0.125]        20
6 (0.125,0.15]        16
```

I want to plot a histogram and density plot using this but I can't seem to find a way of doing so without having to generate new bins etc. Using this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219704/histogram-of-binned-data-frame-in-r) I tried to do the following:-

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x= binRange, y=Frequency)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity")
```

but it crashes. Anyone know of how to deal with this?

Thank you

Comment: Check out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18219704/histogram-of-binned-data-frame-in-r).

Comment: Thanks for that, just updated my post. I tried to do it for my data, so I performed `p <- ggplot(data, aes(x= binRange, y=Frequency)) + geom_histogram(stat="identity")` but it just crashes

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: replace `geom_histogram` with `geom_bar`

Comment: Well it's mainly when I go to print it, I get the following error:- `Error in withCallingHandlers (tryCatch (evalq((function (i)     :   object '.rcpp_warning_recorder' not found`

Comment: I get the same problem with geom_bar as well

Comment: do you want x to be interpreted as the starting and endpoints of your bars? or as a factor-variable?

Comment: As the starting and endpoints of the bar. Just realised as well that the x (i.e. binRange) is a factor which might be causing the problem

Comment: Ah that isn't it. Just converted the factor to character but it still crashes, producing the same error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is that ggplot doesnt understand the data the way you input it, you need to reshape it like so (I am not a regex-master, so surely there are better ways to do is):

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                 binRange Frequency
1    (0,0.025]        88
2 (0.025,0.05]        72
3 (0.05,0.075]        92
4  (0.075,0.1]        38
5  (0.1,0.125]        20
6 (0.125,0.15]        16")

library(stringr)
library(splitstackshape)
library(ggplot2)
# extract the numbers out,
df$binRange <- str_extract(df$binRange, "[0-9].*[0-9]+")

# split the data using the , into to columns:
# one for the start-point and one for the end-point
df <- cSplit(df, "binRange")

# plot it, you actually dont need the second column
ggplot(df, aes(x = binRange_1, y = Frequency, width = 0.025)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", breaks=seq(0,0.125, by=0.025))
```

or if you don't want the data to be interpreted numerically, you can just simply do the following:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
                 binRange Frequency
1    (0,0.025]        88
2 (0.025,0.05]        72
3 (0.05,0.075]        92
4  (0.075,0.1]        38
5  (0.1,0.125]        20
6 (0.125,0.15]        16")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = binRange, y = Frequency)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

you won't be able to plot a density-plot with your data, given its not continous but rather categorical, thats why I actually prefer the second way of showing it,

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = binRange, y = Frequency)) + geom_col()
```